# List display unable to be sorted/ordered (non-pk)

Tags: django, django-admin

for some reason, in Django admin, it won't let me order/sort (asscending) for my price field (using **list_display**).

Other elements can be sorted, but not elements which exist outside of the pk.

How can this be achieved

Models.py-------

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField ("Name", max_length=400)
    link = models.URLField("Link", max_length=900)

class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=False, null=False)
    variation = models.CharField (max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.variation

class Price(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField("Price", decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    variation = models.ForeignKey(Variation, blank=False, null=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Admin.py--------

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',  'price',)
    order_by = ('price',)

    def price(self, obj):
        try:
            price = Price.objects.filter(variation__product=obj)[0].price
        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            None
        else:
            return format_html('${0}', price)
```

Comment: *not elements which exist outside of the pk.*  -- what does this mean?

Comment: What I mean is an element that doesnt exist within the class (primary key), and is not a foreignkey/m2m. I dont know the proper term for this.

Answer (score 0):

You cant try to use ordering attribute add admin_order_field to your price field in admin like this:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',  'price',)
    ordering = ('variation__price',)

    def price(self, obj):
        try:
            price = Price.objects.filter(variation__product=obj)[0].price
        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            None
    else:
        return '${0}'.format(price)
    price.admin_order_field = 'variation__price'
```

Comment: Thanks but this did not work. I've triple checked your example, but it still will not let me sort via price (the list displays but cannot be ordered).